# Flex box ignoring width if input in flexitem

Tags: html, css, input, flexbox

it seems like i didn't understand the flexbox right.

But i think the with of a div in a flexboxitem is ignored.

Like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/34f9awsk/6/

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.ele {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 3;
}

.ele1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.ele input {
  display: inline;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ele ele3" style="background-color: red;">
    <input type="number" size="4" value="9999" />
  </div>
  <div class="ele ele1" style="background-color: green;">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="ele ele3" style="background-color: yellow;">
    <input type="number" size="4" value="9999" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flexbox items has a `min-width` that defaults to `auto`, which means they won't shrink below their contents width.

In this case your `input` element has a default width set in the user agent style sheet, which then dictate the size of the flex item.

Give the `ele` a `min-width: 0` and it will work as expected.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.ele {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 3;
  min-width: 0;
}

.ele1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.ele input {
  display: inline;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ele ele3" style="background-color: red;">
    <input type="number" value="9999" />
  </div>
  <div class="ele ele1" style="background-color: green;">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="ele ele3" style="background-color: yellow;">
    <input type="number" value="9999" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped me!
But now i want a "€" after the input and this isn't also not working. 
Please a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/34f9awsk/10/

Comment: @Flo If it helped an upvote/accept would be appreciated. Regarding the "€", I will take a look later and suggest a solution.